# What is the difference between defining web.config endpoints and registering global.asax routes?

Tags: wcf, endpoint, wcf-endpoint

What is the difference between defining endpoints in web.config and registering routes in global.asax (for the services) like the following:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(
        new ServiceRoute(
            "", 
            new WebServiceHostFactory(), 
            typeof(PersonService)
        )
    );    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the runtime goes, the endpoints are the same. But for IIS-hosted services, if you don't use routes, then the endpoint address will always have the .svc in them - i.e., http://your-computer/app/service.svc/endpoint1. Some people don't like it, especially for REST services, where the .svc doesn't belong in *pure* URLs.

The drawback of using routes is that you need to use the ASP.NET pipeline, which is a problem for some services (IIRC it has a small performance penalty, and by default WCF services don't allow it, you need to explicitly allow the ASP.NET compatibility mode).